# Is it possible to remove the border from RouteBoxer-boxes?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, routeboxer

**EDIT** This question has been answered but I've clarified it for future readers.

[RouteBoxer](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/routeboxer/docs/examples.html) provides a solution of 'boxing in' a route in Google maps so that I can list various points of interest along that route. This technic though creates borders around each box presented on the map. I've attached an image to describe what it looks like.

[image: An example image of what kind of borders I want to remove]

The code produced to create RouteBoxer looks like this:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/routeboxer/src/RouteBoxer.js"></script>

var directionService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var rboxer = new RouteBoxer();
var distance = 20; // km

directionService.route(request, function(result, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

    // Box the overview path of the first route
    var path = result.routes[0].overview_path;
    var boxes = routeBoxer.box(path, distance);

    for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
      var bounds = box[i];
      // Perform search over this bounds 
    }
  }
});
```

Is it possible to remove the borders surrounding each box on the map?

Comment: This question is clear, it has a picture explaining what I aim for and relevant coding. Now... why did you (whoever you are) downvote the question? What can be improved to make it both clearer and worth plus votes?

Comment: I dislike downvotes without explanation :( Have made some balance. The closevote is also odd.

Comment: Wow - is there really a close vote too? It makes me wonder what I actually should write to be considered asking a proper question... Thanks @davidkonrad for your support. ThankS to people like you I actually improve my learning curve which should be the intention with SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have full control. Here is the example above in a fiddle, without black borders -> **http://jsfiddle.net/ftgr8dyp/** Look at the function `drawBoxes()` :

```js
function drawBoxes(boxes) {
     boxpolys = new Array(boxes.length);
     for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
         boxpolys[i] = new google.maps.Rectangle({
             bounds: boxes[i],
             fillOpacity: 0, 
             strokeOpacity: 1.0, 
             strokeColor: '#000000', //<-- change color 
             strokeWeight: 0, //<-- change strokeWeight from 1 to 0
             map: map
         });
     }
}
```

It is standard `google.maps.Rectangle`'s [**you can style as you are used to**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#RectangleOptions). There is nothing in the [RouterBoxer-code](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/routeboxer/src/RouteBoxer.js) that forces certain design or styles.

Comment: That is so neat. :) perfect - it was exactly what I was asking for. I find it somewhat hard to find reasonable answers to these questions in Google maps help documentation.